# Moving div dynamically with CSS

Tags: html, css

I had this structure and I want div "icon" to move dynamically when text is long

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

```css
.tit {
  display: table;
}

.icon {
  border-top: 5px solid currentcolor;
border-right: 5px solid currentcolor;
min-width: 42px;
float: left;
height: 22px;
margin-top: -23px;
margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tit">Titleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
<div class="icon"></div>
```

Comment: Can you specify a bit more, what do you mean by move dynamically? You want the icon to move when the text body is too long, but remain where it is if it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrapper as flexbox.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  border-top: 5px solid currentcolor;
  border-right: 5px solid currentcolor;
  min-width: 42px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tit">Titleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `div class="tit"` in `div class="icon"`

```
<div class="icon">
  <div class="tit">Titleeeeeeeeeee</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4mppb2g7/1/)

Comment: Why can't you put the whole example in the snippet? Just note that jsfiddle is not accessible to all of them...

Comment: Sorry, never used snippet yet, will try now.

Comment: Yea please... Ctrl + M...